# Write a one column in existing excel file using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to write the values of the list `values` only on column "F" of the existing excel file, for example:

```
values = [5, 7, 1]
wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()
items = [i for i in values] 
for item in items:
    ws.append([item])

wb.save('newfile.xlsx')
```

```
ID   Name View  #RightSwipe #LeftSwipe  
145  abc    5   2   1   
146  xyz    8   3   6   
147  pqr    3   4   3
```

add one column in last that's name "Order"

```
Order
5
7
1
```

Answer (score 0):

`append` adds new rows at the end of the file. You want to add data to existing rows. Simply iterate over the list and add the values in their respective rows, at the last column:

```py
ws.cell(row=1, column=ws.max_column+1, value="Order")
for row_num, value in enumerate(values, start=2):
    ws.cell(row=row_num, column=ws.max_column, value=value)
```

You can also use the [`iter_rows`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells) to iterate the rows while [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)ping the values:

```
for row, value in zip(ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=ws.max_column, max_col=ws.max_column), values):
    row[0].value = value
```

Comment: Use `iter_rows(min_col=6, max_col=6)` to avoid the need for a counter.

Comment: Thanks for that @CharlieClark ! I kept both because it seems to get more complicated. Am I using it wrong? Is there a performance gain using `iter_rows`?

Comment: There's no performance gain but I think it makes sense to let openpyxl do the counting for you. I also wouldn't bother with `zip` here `for row in iter_rows(…); cell = row[0]; cell.value = next(values)` to keep it concise but less magical.